# How do I eliminate all of the word in text file on Matlab

Tags: matlab

I get my output as below:

[image]

But I have to eliminate the word feature, and get the output as below:
[image]

Comment: Please don't add tags which are unrelated to the problem. If you don't want the word `feature` in your output, replace `str1 =[str1 [' feature',num2str(c1),':' num2str(feature(c2,c1))] ];` with         `str1 =[str1 [' ',num2str(c1),':' num2str(feature(c2,c1))] ];`

Comment: Because I do not post my code here, it may help if need any modification of previous code instead of write a new code.

Comment: Fair enough, I see the reason for a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To post-process such a text file, use `regexprep`:

```
>> fid=fopen('myfile.txt','r');
>> dat = fread(fid,'*char')'; %' read in characters, store in char array
>> fclose(fid);
>> dat_new = regexprep(dat,'feature','')
dat_new =
1 1:1 2:1 3:1 4:0 5:1 

0 1:0 2:1 3:0 4:1 5:-1 

0 1:1 2:0 3:0 4:1 5:-1 

0 1:0 2:0 3:0 4:1 5:1 

0 1:1 2:0 3:0 4:0 5:-1 

1 1:1 2:0 3:1 4:1 5:1 

0 1:0 2:0 3:0 4:1 5:-1
```

To write the new file;

```
fid = fopen('myfile_new.txt','w');
fwrite(fid,dat_new);
fclose(fid);
```